# Minecraft /testfor player's relative altitude

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been working on an "infinite elytra flight" thingy and came across into an issue. I want to make the player goes up when reaching a certain distance from the ground.

I know I can use the command

```
/testfor @p [x=coord y=coord z=coord]
```

This command can `/testfor` a player's `y` coordinates, but how to detect his/her relative altitude from the ground?

Comment: Why downvote, please explain so I can improve it.

Comment: You're unlikely to get an answer as to why your question was downvoted, but on the whole, I think it's a good question. I typically recommend against the use of `testfor`, but it might be useful here.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: I am not 100% familiar with Minecraft commands, but I may have found a way according to the wiki.

You can use the `/testforblock` command to check whether a certain block is in a certain location. This command can be run using the Tilde notation (~3, for example), to get a relative location towards the command execution. You can then prefix that with the /execute command to execute it at a player's location.

Another thing you can do is instead of using coordinates is specifying a radius using [r=R].

putting those together, you can do one of 2 things:

1. find a player and test if any of the common "top layer blocks" like sand, gravel, stone, dirt or grass blocks are within X blocks on the Y Axis. If the command is true, teleport the detected player upwards..
2. for every top block in the infinite elytra area, select all players that are within a certain range and teleport them upwards.

Comment: I don't think you can use the `[r=R]` selector like this.  That changes which entity gets selected, but with `testforblock`, you not dealing with an entity.